# Strange squished notes and can grace notes be tied? (is what I'm seeing a slur?)

Tags: piano, sheet-music

Piece is traümerei, what does this squished note mean (the conjoined crotchet and semibreve) and how do I play it?
[image: squished note image]

Also can grace notes be tied? Or is any kind of connecting line on a grace note a slur no matter the pitch of the subsequent note?
[image: tied grace note?]

Sorry for image quality
Thanks to all who can help!

Comment: Ouch my eyes!  please try to take in-focus pictures -- no need to get that close to the page

Answer (score 7):

In the first instance the "extra" crotchet is there because there are in effect two lines of music going on in the lower staff.  One voice is the semibreve low F lasting for the whole bar.  The other voice is a crotchet low F followed by the dotted minim C/A chord 1 beat later.  It is that crotchet that tells you that the C/A chord is meant to be played on the second beat.

The second one:  yes that is a tie.  So you play low B flat, then F (and hold it) then the D.